# XamNumericEditor Double only takes 9 digits - always

Tags: .net, wpf, infragistics, xamdatagrid

Good morning,

I've a problem with a XamNumericEditor. Even if I set the digits on the mask to something bigger than 9 it only takes 9 significative digits. However if I set it to something smaller than 9 it works. It seems like there is a limit of "9" when editing data type double, is it?

Here is the style I use:

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type igEditors:XamNumericEditor}" >

     <Setter  Property="Mask" Value="{}{double:11.2:c}" />

</Style>
```

I am using XamDatagrid version 11.1.

I also posted this on Infragistics community but no answer this far.

What am I missing? Am I doing something wrong?

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Is this the related thread on the Infragistics site? If so, did installing the service release resolve the issue?  http://www.infragistics.com/community/forums/t/86441.aspx

Comment: @Alhalama, yes it is and it was solved there, thanks for updating this post.